# Upgrading PHP-FPM while minimizing downtime

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, php-fpm, update

I am running nginx 1.2.6 on Ubuntu. With nginx, I can [perform upgrades gracefully](http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine#Upgrading_To_a_New_Binary_On_The_Fly), so that no incoming requests will be lost.

**Is there any process like that for PHP-FPM? If so, what is the process for doing the upgrade?** Is it possible to ask PHP-FPM to reload `php.ini` with no downtime?

**If not, what's the next best way to perform the upgrade?** Taking into account:

- that, we minimize downtime.
- Ensure that all current requests are performed and finished.

Note that our setup currently only consists of 1 server, with all services running on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can install second instance of php-fpm with another port of socket it doesn't matter, change in the nginx config port or socket to new php-fpm and "perform upgrades gracefully".
After you can remove old php-fpm.